# Simulate FORCE TOUCH on any mac

Tags: macos, touch, simulate

OSX's new force touch seems like a great way to extend the functionality of an input device, however it only works with the new macbooks.

Since the OS supports the feature, is there anyway to trick it into thinking that a long press is a force touch?

Thanks.